# Checar se id_usuario está logado (session - codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou construindo um sistema de login e nele estou fazendo algumas validações. Tudo funcional, exceto, a verificação se usuário já está logado.

Estou utilizando o método abaixo, porem não está 100% funcional. O que pretendo é verificar se o usuário que está tentando realizar o login já está logado em alguma sessão.

***O que quero é impedir que um mesmo usuário tenha duas sessões.***

Código de método:

```
private function _valida_usuario_logado()
{
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $ci_sessions = $this->auditoria->listar_ci_sessions();//$this->db->get('tbl_ci_sessions');      

    foreach($ci_sessions->result() as $item)
    {           
        $user_data = $item->user_data;
        $sessions = unserialize($user_data);

        $id_logado = $sessions['id'];           
    }

    if ($id == $id_logado)
    {           
        echo 'ja_logado';           
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'nao_logado';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu recomendo o uso de um _helper_ ou um _hook_. Esse seu método só vai fazer essa validação dentro da própria classe dele, e o ideal é que seja global, ou não é? Pelo que vejo aí, ele está verificando se já existe sessão no banco, e se já existir, ele imprime uma mensagem e encerra a execução. Então o seu problema não é checar se existe a sessão, mas saber o que fazer depois de checar, correto?

Comment: Na verdade meu problema está sendo checar mesmo, pois não está funcional.
Porque ele está impedindo um login, de um usuário que nem está logado.

Quero fazer o seguinte: meu usuário tem o ID 1, se este ID já estiver logado em outro navegador, maquina, etc, então impede que o login seja feito, caso contrário, permite que o login seja feito.

Eu estou buscado o retorno `ja_logado` por ajax e em caso de sucesso faço o redirecionamento da pagina por ajax.

Comment: O pulo do gato é *timestamp*. Pra usar dados do banco vc teria que validar o tempo de vida dessa sessão com um _timestamp_. Vc pode matar a _SESSION_ quando o _browser_ fechar, mas no DB é diferente. Se o usuário loga e depois não desloga, o dado continua (persiste) no DB, e vc vai ter falsos positivos. Depois eu faço uma resposta aqui, mas vc já devia ir tentando algo nesse sentido...

Comment: Tentei um exemplo, mas não foi timestamp e também não deu.

Answer (score 0):

Em cada controle, eu uso da seguinte forma:

```
if($this->session->userdata('logado')==null) redirect('login');
```

Neste caso, logado, é o nome da session que você direcionou. 
Então, a construção ficaria dessa forma:

```
class Interno extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if($this->session->userdata('logado')==null) redirect('login');
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Então, não é este o que quero, eu já tenho isto funcionando. O que quero é impedir que um mesmo usuário tenha duas sessões.

Answer (score 0):

Wagner, acho que não tem como ser feito, também tentei fazer isso.

O que pode ser feito e funciona mais ou menos legalzinho, é criar uma tabela no banco de dados que faz uma marcação ao logar, pois as sessões são individuais por navegador, ai na hora de logar, verificaria se já está logado no banco.

PORÉM, pode acontecer do usuário apenas fechar o navegador em vez de fazer logoff, daí não conseguiria logar mais.

ENTÃO penso que o mais correto seria fazer como a GOOGLE faz, apenas avisar o usuário que foi feto um login na data e horário x, se reconhece esse login ou não. Se ele responder que sim, ai apaga o registro do último login e cria um novo.

Comment: Amigo, as sessions são gravadas no banco de dados, logo assim que o usuário loga, é criado um array com as informações pré-definidas do login.

Se o usuário fechar o navegador sem fazer logoff, nem sempre, a sessão é destruída,  pois ela está armazenada no cookie, fazendo com que o usuário não perca o id_session, então tem como validar pelo `id_usuario` no `user_data`, na tabela `session`, porém, é aí que está o meu problema, pois o código não está trabalhando 100%. Hora funciona, outrora não.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($this->session->has_userdata('id')){ //Ou o dado que TEM de existir pra estar logado
      echo 'Logado';
  }else{
      echo 'Não logado';
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Você Cria a sessão no banco de dados, e de pois pode armazenar a sessão no navegador do usuário especificando a data e hora na mesma (Local Storage)
Você pode utilizar o javascript pra fazer essa inserção/checagem na Local Storage e redirecionar caso precise.